# Query regarding transit through Heathrow, London

Tags: transit-visas, lhr, connecting-flights

Do I need a UK transit visa if my layover in Heathrow is for 2 hours? I will land at Terminal 5 and depart from Terminal 3. I won't leave the airport. My flight is from New Delhi to Vancouver. I have a connecting flight so collecting baggage isn't an issue. Please help me.

I am an Indian citizen and I will have a Canadian visa by then.

Comment: Please add your citizenship and any residence permits as this can affect your need for a visa

Comment: I am an Indian citizen and I have permit to stay in Vancouver